# Configuring the JMeter script to distribute the load for the given configuration

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I'm new to JMeter, but recently I have been asked to create a JMeter script for the below scenario.

> There is only 1 GET API request. This GET request should be called 77 times throughout 1h using 8 threads, but 2 threads should be executed parallelly.

After learning about JMeter quickly, I did some research about how to do such a task. So, I learned that if I use **Stepping Thread Group**, it will be easy to do the given scenario. Then I learned about **Stepping Thread Group**, but still, I was unable to come up with a proper configuration. Please can anyone let me know how to do a such scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need any plugins for that. "Normal" [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) will be sufficient.

[image]

With regards to other requirements they can be achieved using [JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer), i.e. for running a request 77 times per hour you can use [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)

[image]

the requirement of "2 threads should be executed parallelly" doesn't make a lot of sense to me as the load is too low to care about the concurrency.

- 77 requests per hour means that you should send 1 request each 47 seconds
- given you have 8 users it means that each user sends a request each 376 seconds

the chance of 2 requests will be fired at the same time is minimal given even distribution of users. However if this is a strict requirement you need to implement - take a look at [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)

[image]

this way requests will be send in batches of 2 at the same moment